Was Paul’s perfection delayed for our sake?
Corinthians and Philippians( 3:12) seem to indicate Paul is still running the race towards attaining perfection/full maturity.
In Ephesians 3:13 Paul tells us not to be discouraged because his sufferings are for our glory( glorification/completion).  So could it be that Paul is held back intentionally and willingly on his own glorification so that he might show us the way better ?  And if so Paul truly suffered for our sake.
Note that rest of Ephesians 3 is about attaining the fullness of God/ glorification.

Welcome to SE-BH. Please see the Tour and the Help as to the purpose and the functioning of the site. I think your question would improve (and be more in keeping with the site's requirements) if you quoted your two texts in full and concentrated on determining their meaning, rather than concentrate on your own supposition. Let the text speak to us, as we analyse it.

I would answer no on two counts.
First, Paul did not teach that perfection was even a possibility for him, even though he might be "perfectly mature." He specifically urged Christians not to be so arrogant as to think that they had reached it.
Philippians 3

10 ...that I may know Him and the power of His resurrection... 11 in
order that I may attain to the resurrection from the dead. 12 Not that
I have already obtained it or have already become perfect, but I
press on so that I may lay hold of that for which also I was laid hold
of by Christ Jesus. 13 Brethren, I do not regard myself as having
laid hold of it yet; but one thing I do: forgetting what lies behind
and reaching forward to what lies ahead, 14 I press on toward the goal
for the prize of the upward call of God in Christ Jesus. 15 Let us, then, who are “perfectly mature” adopt this attitude.

Second, in Ephesians, the idea express suffered as "a prisoner of Christ for you Gentiles." (3:1) The Ephesians and other non-Jewish Christians are to not to lose faith on account of his sufferings, which are "for your glory."

I became a minister by the gift of God’s grace that was granted me in
accord with the exercise of his power. 8 To me, the very least of all
the holy ones, this grace was given, to preach to the Gentiles the
inscrutable riches of Christ... 11 This was according to the eternal purpose that he
accomplished in Christ Jesus our Lord, 12 in whom we have boldness of
speech and confidence of access through faith in him. 13 So I ask you
not to lose heart over my afflictions for you; this is your glory.

Conclusion: Paul did not teach that his perfection was delayed for our sake. Ephesians says his persecution would ultimately bring glory to the cause of Christ, and especially to the gentile churches such as the one at Ephesus.

Paul fought the fight to keep and grow in the faith like every believer fights.
Paul attained a faith closer to perfection than most average believers, but we are to strive toward perfection. He got closer to it over time as we do… if we continue to seek, knock, etc.
Any delay in our life is mostly our choices and our effort, as with Paul and other Bible characters.  God offers us everything needed, He doesn’t hold us back!

Welcome to the Biblical Hermeneutics forum, User125581 (you can choose a more friendly name if you want). Please note that this forum is different than most others because it's focused on supporting any assertions with specific scriptures, opinions of experts, context, linguistic analysis, historical sources or references, and logic to build a case. Typically, these are quoted in questions and any answers for convenience. This doesn't mean the answer you provided is wrong, but only that "hermeneutics" focuses on support for any answer you provide.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

I would answer this question as "no". Paul gives the impression of often getting into conflict. Saul was a zealot that persecuted The Way and then after conversion appeared to continue his zealotry. Ephesians continues:

Join together in following my example, brothers and sisters, and just
as you have us as a model, keep your eyes on those who live as we do.
For, as I have often told you before and now tell you again even
with tears, many live as enemies of the cross of Christ. Their
destiny is destruction, their god is their stomach, and their glory is
in their shame. Their mind is set on earthly things.

This type of criticism of the non-Christian world or, otherwise, criticism of weak Christians, is unhelpful. This is far different from when Jesus taught:

Matthew 5:15-17
15 Neither do people light a lamp and put it under a bowl. Instead
they put it on its stand, and it gives light to everyone in the house.
16 In the same way, let your light shine before others, that they may
see your good deeds and glorify your Father in heaven.

Try to follow the example & teachings of Jesus. Try to be cordial & peaceable towards all people, regardless of their beliefs. Jesus suffered conflict in Judea due to the zealotry of Pharisees such as Saul. Jesus was ultimately subjected to the Pharisee Law rather than to Roman Law. But when living outside of Judea, I would guess many Christians engaged in provocative Jewish-like zealotry bringing them into conflict with non-Christians. Sorry but I do not believe Paul was a good example. Christianity is not for everyone & we should learn to be fully peacefully accepting of this.
For example, when Christians from this Stack Exchange visit the Buddhism Stack Exchange, seeking to mock & ridicule Buddhism, this is unworthy of Christ. The word "love" means love. It does not mean the opposite.
Jesus said to reach perfection, we must not judge, not condemn, forgive & give (Luke 6:36-38). We do not have to suffer as Jesus suffered because Jesus was the final sacrifice.

I gave you an upvote to cancel one of the downvotes because I think any downvote should be explained. Also, simple disagreement is not sufficient for a downvote in my opinion. Dhammadhatu, you suggested that Paul remained a zealot, which might be so, but let me point out a couple of things in a verse you quoted: "For, as I have often told you before and now tell you again even with tears, many live as enemies of the cross . . ." Here, Paul shows that he cares deeply for people who say they're Christians but don't act like Christians, but rather they live selfish and sinful lives!

@Dieter. Other than the first sentence, "I would answer this question as "no".", it's not obvious how any of this answer relates to the original question. It all seems to be a patronizing put-down of Christianity and its beliefs. E.g. "I do not believe Paul was a good example", "Christians engaged in provocative Jewish-like zealotry bringing them into conflict with non-Christians.", "Christianity is not for everyone", "Christians from this Stack Exchange visit the Buddhism Stack Exchange, seeking to mock & ridicule Buddhism", and a general rant.

@Ray, Yes, I agree with you. The zeal of Saul of Tarsus changed, but zeal is not necessarily a sin, otherwise the times that Jesus drove out the money changers (monetary exchange service workers) from the Temple would also qualify as a sin in light of John 2:17, "His disciples remembered that it was written, “Zeal for your house will consume me.” Similarly, not all things people label as "love" is compatible with the Word of God.

Hello guys. Paul was in the PLURALISTIC Roman Empire. Obviously his troubles & ultimate demise was due to provocative actions and disrespecting others. The Roman attitude towards Christianity was quite clear, accusing it of hating mankind. I already provided the example of the lack of respect a member of this forum shows when he visits forums of other doctrines.

@Dhammadhatu says "I already provided the example of the lack of respect …". Where is that example provided?

@RayButterworth if I may presume to answer, the OP seems to refer to Paul's statement: " Their destiny is destruction, their god is their stomach, and their glory is in their shame." We need not adopt Paul's example of insulting those who do not accept Christ. Especially when we visit sites devoted to other faiths.

@Dhammadhatu I hope you will not be discouraged from continuing to participate here despite the downvotes. I agree with your statement that Paul's attitude (expressed to the Ephesian church, not to non-believers) should not be adopted by other Christians when visiting SE sites devoted to other faiths. Mutual respect is the proper posture.

@DanFefferman says "the OP seems to refer to Paul's statement …". No, I cut the quotation off too soon. "I already provided the example of the lack of respect …" should have been "I already provided the example of the lack of respect a member of this forum shows when he visits forums of other doctrines.".
